# Assistance if you may

Tags: kali-linux, professional-education

I am currently doing general IT for a software company and my main focus is switching into security.. that being said my question is about the opinion here in regards to:

https://www.offensive-security.com/

I am going to attempt to build a use case and proposition my boss with assistance in paying for these certifications.. the main question is: Has anyone here attempted or gained any of these certifications? Are they worth it (Money, Time, the experience)? Do they actually effect my ability to move up in my career.. such as working towards becoming a security engineer/Pen tester full time?
I'm currently working my way through several books (Security +) and some https://www.udemy.com/ courses as well. I have Linux knowledge to at least an intermediate level and my job is in a windows environment.
I apologize if this is the incorrect area to post this.. any advice or information is deeply appreciated.. thanks all..

Comment: Welcome! As it currently stands, your question appears mostly opinion-based which would be off-topic here because that makes it hard to give a definitive answer. Also, a more descriptive title would be great. :)